# How to deal with Hashtable property of entity in database using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binaryformatter

I have old project which used ADO.NET to access the persistent store. Currently, I want to migrate it to EF (6.1.3, if it matters), in order to support several DB providers with minimal code duplicate.

There is an entity, which contains `Hashtable` property:

```
public class Record
{
    ...
    public Hashtable data { get; set; }
}
```

With ADO.NET, the `BinaryFormatter` was used to convert this `data` property to the BLOB, and vice versa:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    result = stream.GetBuffer();
}

//----------

using (MemoryStream serializationStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    result = (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(serializationStream);
}
```

Now I need to tell EF how it should store and retrieve that property.

**What have I tried**

I could store one more property in the entity:

```
public class Record
{
    public byte[] dataRaw { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Hashtable data {
        get {/*deserialize dataRaw */ }
        set { /*Serialize to dataRaw*/}
    }
}
```

But this solution is prone to errors, and special workflow with that property must be followed.

**P.S.** Actually this question is not about the Hashtable only, but about every custom class which must be stored and retrived in a special way.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is possible. I don't think there are any hooks that would allow the value to be coerced into and out of a sql primitive. I am eagerly watching this question to see if there are any answers that come close.

Comment: there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135642/in-entity-framework-is-there-a-cleaner-way-of-converting-an-object-type-to-a-str, it uses a backing field like yours. I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a complete solution based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135642/in-entity-framework-is-there-a-cleaner-way-of-converting-an-object-type-to-a-str) I mentioned above.
I have tested it in linqpad, and it works rather well.

*You don't need a special workflow, as the property accessors take care of saving and loading the hash table when needed.*

**Main Method**

```
void Main()
{
    using (var ctx = new TestContext())
    {
        var hash = new Hashtable();
        hash.Add("A", "A");
        ctx.Settings.Add(new Settings { Hash = hash });
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        // load them up...
        ctx.Settings.ToArray().Select(_ => _.Hash).Dump();
    }
}
```

**Settings Class**

```
public class Settings
{
    // a primary key is necessary.
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Hashtable Hash
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // the backing field can be protected, this helps 'hide' it.
    protected virtual byte[] _Hash
    {
        get
        {
            return Hash.ToBinary();
        }
        set     
        {
            Hash = value.FromBinary<Hashtable>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Extensions to Convert the Values**

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static BinaryPropertyConfiguration BinaryProperty<T>(
        this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> mapper,
        String propertyName) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        Expression expr = arg;

        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName,
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);

        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);

        Expression<Func<T, byte[]>> expression = (Expression<Func<T, byte[]>>)lambda;
        return mapper.Property(expression);
    }

    public static byte[] ToBinary<T>(this T instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            return null;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, instance);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T FromBinary<T>(this byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            return default(T);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, false))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var instance = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return (T)instance;
        }
    }
}
```

**Data Context**

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Settings> Settings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Settings>()
            .BinaryProperty("_Hash")
            .HasColumnName("Hashtable");
    }       
}
```

Comment: @hadi yea, it works, I have tried it, saved it to a varbinary(max) - which is what's generated, and loaded it back up - no problem.

Comment: @Jim, this is more elegant solution.

Comment: @stukselbax if this is the  solution then you can accept it no ?

Comment: @sampath - thanks for that, but perhaps the answer is lacking?

Comment: @Sampath I would like to wait for a while before accepting. It solves the problem, but I want to wait others to come to party.

Comment: FYI: I've posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/62), and it turns out that this feature will be [implemented later](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242), but only for new EF.